# Animated offset border css? javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, border

Attached you'll find an image explaining what i'd like to accomplish.
I would like to have my background set, over that I would like to have a border that's a bit offset from the background. In some way I need to find a way to animate every single side of the border by it's own.

I would like the top border to animate in from the right, the bottom one from the left. The left one from the bottom and the right one from the top.

This is giving me a big headache. Anybody have any ideas?

[image]

What I've done is:

```
<div id="#mainsection"></div>
```

The border is created in CSS:

```
#mainsection:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    border: 4px solid #96896C;
}
```

What I've realised is that this is not going to work as I need every border-part as separate items.

Comment: Do you have any code so we can see what you've already done?

Comment: Also animate how - make it flash, make it move?  Please spend a little more time on making this question better as in it's current format, it will be closed

Comment: I havn't managed to get close to what I'm after.

Comment: Show us the code then - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps use linear gradients and a couple of `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements. This wont give you entirely separate animations but the horizontal and vertical borders can be animated separately.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#mainsection {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://placehold.it/1000x1000) center center;
}

#mainsection:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, black), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), linear-gradient(black, black);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 2px 0%, calc(100% - 4px) 100%, 2px 0%;
  background-position: left bottom, 0 0, right top;
  transition: background-size 1.5s ease;
}

#mainsection:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, black), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), linear-gradient(black, black);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 2px, calc(100% - 4px) 100%, 0% 2px;
  background-position: left bottom, 0 0, right top;
  transition: background-size 2s ease .5s; /* .5s delay */
}

#mainsection:hover:after {
  background-size: 2px 100%, calc(100% - 4px) 100%, 2px 100%;
}

#mainsection:hover:before {
  background-size: 100% 2px, calc(100% - 4px) 100%, 100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainsection"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution to @Turnip but by simply using multiple gradient on the same div. And you can control the animation of each one by playing with initial and final values of `background-size` and `background-position`:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding:40px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) top right content-box,  
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) top right content-box,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom left content-box,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom left content-box,
   url(https://placehold.it/1000x1000) center center;
  background-size:0 3px,3px 0,0 3px,3px 0,auto;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:2s;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container:hover {
  background-size:
   100% 3px,
   3px 100%,
   100% 3px,
   3px 100%,
   auto; /* This is for image */
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Then simply adjust the position to control the animation:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding:40px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) top left content-box,  
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) top right content-box,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom right content-box,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom left content-box,
   url(https://placehold.it/1000x1000) center center;
  background-size:0 3px,3px 0,0 3px,3px 0,auto;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:2s;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container:hover {
  background-size:
   100% 3px,
   3px 100%,
   100% 3px,
   3px 100%,
   auto; /* This is for image */
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Another one:

```css
body {
  margin:0
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding:40px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) top content-box,  
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) right content-box,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom content-box,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) left content-box,
   url(https://placehold.it/1000x1000) center center;
  background-size:0 3px,3px 0,0 3px,3px 0,auto;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:2s;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container:hover {
  background-size:
   100% 3px,
   3px 100%,
   100% 3px,
   3px 100%,
   auto; /* This is for image */
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```